# How to preserve source formatting while copying data from word table to excel sheet using VB macro?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I am trying to copy some data from a word table to an excel sheet using a VB Macro.

It is copying the text perfectly as desired.

Now i want to preserve the source formatting present in word doc.

The things I want to preserve are

1. Strike Through
2. Color
3. Bullets
4. New Line Character

I am using the following code to copy -

`objTemplateSheetExcelSheet.Cells(1, 2) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(iRow, iCol).Range.Text)`

### Kindly let me know how I can edit this so as to preserve source formatting.

The logic I am using is as follows -

```
wdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files (*.*),*.*", , _
"Browse for file containing table to be imported") '(Browsing for a file)

If wdFileName = False Then Exit Sub '(user cancelled import file browser)

Set wdDoc = GetObject(wdFileName) '(open Word file)

With wdDoc
    'enter code here`
    TableNo = wdDoc.tables.Count '(Counting no of tables in the document)
    If TableNo = 0 Then
        MsgBox "This document contains no tables", _
        vbExclamation, "Import Word Table"
    End If
End With
```

I am running a table count on the word file. Then for all the tables present in the word doc accessing each row and column of the tables using the above mentioned code.

Ok I am attaching the remaining piece of code as well

```
'Creating TemplateSheet object
Set objTemplateSheetExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
'Opening the template to be used
objTemplateSheetExcelApp.Workbooks.Open ("C:\Temp\Documents Page XX_US-VC Combo Template.xlsx")
Set objTemplateSheetExcelWkBk = objTemplateSheetExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(5)
Set objTemplateSheetExcelSheet = objTemplateSheetExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(5) '(Selecting the desired tab)

tblcount = 1
For tblcount = 1 To TableNo
    With .tables(tblcount)
    'copy cell contents from Word table cells to Excel cells
    For iRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
        For iCol = 1 To .Columns.Count
            On Error Resume Next
            strEach = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(iRow, iCol).Range.Text)
            For arrycnt = 0 To 15
                YNdoc = InStr(strEach, myArray(arrycnt))
                    If (YNdoc > 0) Then
                        objTemplateSheetExcelSheet.Cells(2, yourArray(arrycnt)) = _
                        WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(iRow, iCol + 1).Range.Text)
                            If arrycnt = 3 Or arrycnt = 6 Then
                                objTemplateSheetExcelSheet.Cells(2, yourArray(arrycnt) + 1) = _
                                WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(iRow + 1, iCol + 1).Range.Text)
                            End If
                    End If
            Next arrycnt
        Next iCol
    Next iRow
    End With
    Next tblcount
End With
intRow = 1

'To save the file
strFileName = "Newfile.xlsx"
objTemplateSheetExcelWkBk.SaveAs strFld & "\" & strFileName

objTemplateSheetExcelApp.Quit

Set objTemplateSheetExcelApp = Nothing
Set objTemplateSheetExcelWkBk = Nothing
Set objTemplateSheetExcelSheet = Nothing

Set wdDoc = Nothing
```

Comment: How are you copying from word?

Comment: I have added my logic above itself.

Comment: The code above doesn't include code for copying?

Comment: I have edited the file to contain the entire code now.
The line "WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(iRow, iCol).Range.Text)" is the main code for copying the data from word.

Comment: Are you doing this from Excel VBA or Word VBA?

Comment: In that case you really are doing it in a very complex way. Let me post an answer with an example. Gimme some time. It will be a very long post...

Comment: Phew!! Done :) let me know if you still have any problems.

Answer (score 8):

To interact with Word from Excel, you can choose either Early Binding or Late Binding. I am using Late Binding where you do not need to add any references.

I will cover the code in 5 parts

1. Binding with a Word Instance
2. Opening the Word document
3. Interacting with Word Table
4. Declaring Your Excel Objects
5. Copying the word table to Excel

---

A. Binding with a Word Instance

---

Declare your Word objects and then bind with either an existing instance of Word or create a new instance. For example

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim oWordApp As Object, oWordDoc As Object

    '~~> Establish an Word application object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oWordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set oWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0

    oWordApp.Visible = True
End Sub
```

---

B. Opening the Word document

---

Once you have connected with/created the Word instance, simply open the word file.. See this example

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim oWordApp As Object, oWordDoc As Object
    Dim FlName As String

    FlName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files (*.Doc*),*.Doc*", , _
             "Browse for file containing table to be imported")

    '~~> Establish an Word application object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oWordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set oWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0

    oWordApp.Visible = True

    '~~> Open the Word document
    Set oWordDoc = oWordApp.Documents.Open(FlName)
End Sub
```

---

C. Interacting with Word Table

---

Now you have the document open, Let's connect with say Table1 of the word document.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim oWordApp As Object, oWordDoc As Object
    Dim FlName As String
    Dim tbl As Object

    FlName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files (*.Doc*),*.Doc*", , _
             "Browse for file containing table to be imported")

    '~~> Establish an Word application object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oWordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set oWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0

    oWordApp.Visible = True

    Set oWordDoc = oWordApp.Documents.Open(FlName)

    Set tbl = oWordDoc.Tables(1)
End Sub
```

---

D. Declaring Your Excel Objects

---

Now we have the handle to the Word Table. Before we copy it, let's set our Excel objects.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim oWordApp As Object, oWordDoc As Object
    Dim FlName As String
    Dim tbl As Object

    FlName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files (*.Doc*),*.Doc*", , _
             "Browse for file containing table to be imported")

    '~~> Establish an Word application object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oWordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set oWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0

    oWordApp.Visible = True

    Set oWordDoc = oWordApp.Documents.Open(FlName)

    Set tbl = oWordDoc.Tables(1)

    '~~> Excel Objects
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Temp\Documents Page XX_US-VC Combo Template.xlsx")

    Set ws = wb.Sheets(5)
End Sub
```

---

E. Copying the word table to Excel

---

And finally when we have the destination all set, simply copy the table from word to Excel. See this.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim oWordApp As Object, oWordDoc As Object
    Dim FlName As String
    Dim tbl As Object

    FlName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files (*.Doc*),*.Doc*", , _
             "Browse for file containing table to be imported")

    '~~> Establish an Word application object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oWordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set oWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0

    oWordApp.Visible = True

    Set oWordDoc = oWordApp.Documents.Open(FlName)

    Set tbl = oWordDoc.Tables(1)

    '~~> Excel Objects
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Temp\Documents Page XX_US-VC Combo Template.xlsx")

    Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)

    tbl.Range.Copy

    ws.Range("A1").Activate

    ws.Paste
End Sub
```

**SCREENSHOT**

***Word Document***

[image]

***Excel (After Pasting)***

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey Siddharth, thanks alot for that. Ill i'mplement it in my code and get back to you....

Comment: Sid :)  this one is awesome ..Well explained +1

Comment: @SathishKothandam: Thanks for taking time to appreciate it :)