# Copying text from word using vba to an excel cell

Tags: html, excel, vba, ms-word, ms-office

I have an issue regarding vba. I`m trying to copy the text content from word documents into an excel sheet to a specific cell. Now, I have no trouble copying the content as a single string, but I would like to keep formatting. I have tried using the following:

```
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Microsoft Word 8.0 Document Object"
```

But sadly it only copies an image of the document (albeit in the right cell).

Is there a way to do this using vba? There are hundreds of documents, therefore doing it by hand is not feasible.

Alternatively, If this is not possible, I would also be happy, if the documents are pasted as html with indications for line breaks and spacing.

Thank you for your help!

**Edit 28/7, 13:18:**

```
'Create an instance of the FileSystemObject
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Get the folder object
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\afloder")
i = 10

'loop through each file in the directory and prints their names
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    'print file name
    temp = CStr(objFile.Name)
    splittedTemp = Split(temp, ".")
    Cells(i + 1, 1) = splittedTemp(0)

    'paste in the content
    Doc = CStr("C:\afolder\" & objFile.Name)
    Set WordDoc = Word.Documents.Open(Doc)
    Word.ActiveDocument.Content.Copy

    'Call the paste procedure
    Worksheets("Communication Template").Cells(i + 1, 9).Select
    DoEvents
    ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Microsoft Word 8.0 Document Object", DisplayAsIcon:=False

    WordDoc.Close savechanges:=False
    Set WordDoc = Nothing

    i = i + 1
Next objFile

Set WordApp = Nothing
```

Comment: Can you post rest of your code? that 1 line will probably make more sense if we can see the rest of the code

Comment: I have posted the rest for this (not the string copy paste). Hope it helps !

Comment: There are several answers to this question on StackOverflow: [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12248308/4717755) from @SiddartthRout is comprehensive.

Comment: Hey @PeterT thank you for your comment! I have seen and read this before I posted, however it does not seem to deal with my issue, as it is copying tables and not textual content and formatting of the word document. As I said, I can copy the content of the document, but I need to either:
 A, Keep the formatting (line breaks, spacing, etc) of the document, or
B, Copy is as html where linebreaks, spacing, etc are marked.